# Изменения размера элемента при масштабировании страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я хочу, чтобы когда я масштабировал / уменьшал страницу, элемент автоматически увеличивался / уменьшался.
Мой код:

```css
.element1 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">
</div>
```

Почему этот код не работает? :(

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `auto` значит: "сколько надо, чтобы поместилось содержимое и не больше".
В Вашем случае можно сделать так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.element1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.element1 {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1"></div>
```

`html` и `body` нужны, потому что 100% считаются от родителя.

Answer (score 2):

То что вы хотите сделать, возможно сделать несколькими способами.
Вот способ с помощью `flex`. Элемент ведёт себя как блочный и выкладывает содержимое согласно флекс-модели:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex{ 
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}
.element1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
.element2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="element1"> block 1 </div>
  <div class="element2"> block 2 </div>
</div>
```

*Ссылки:*

[Используем CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
[Flexbox песочница](https://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/)
[Flexbox Froggy шикарная визуальная песочница, для понимания принципов работы](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)